# Problems with running dynamic loop in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script that is supposed to go in each sub-directory (3 of them) and cut the 2nd field of a config file and create a new file containing it. It should have 3 separate files but instead, it's creating only one. The problem is that my script is taking all the config files from all of the them and combining it in one file. Here is my simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
    listdir="/opt/logs/"
    cut -d "," -f2 $listdir/*/*.logs > client1.log
done
```

Now, I know * means everything and that it does but what I want to do is cut the second field from the original log file for each client and create a new file dynamically in it's directory. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch...

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually iterate over the directories:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for d in /opt/logs/*; do
    log="client.$(basename "$d").log"
    cut -d "," -f2 "$d"/*.logs > "$log"
done
```

Comment: When I run the script, I get this error: cut -d , -f2 /opt/log/client1/client1.dat
./loop.sh: line 5: : No such file or directory. But the file does exist. The client directories are named SYSclient, patchadm and systemadm. So I need to cut the 2nd field for the log file for SYSclient.log, patchadm.log and systemadm.log files. The file structure is /opt/log/SYSclient, /opt/log/patchadm and /opt/log/systemadm

Comment: dunno. run your script with `bash -vx scriptname` and see if the debugging output reveals anything.